# My R code isn't throwing any errors, but it's not doing what it's supposed to

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv, data-cleaning, import-from-csv

Some background for my question: This is an R script that a previous research assistant wrote, but he did not provide any guidance to me on using it for myself. After working through an R textbook, I attempted to use the code on my data files.

What this code is supposed to do is load multiple .csv files, delete certain items/columns from them, and then write the new cleaned .csv files to a specified directory.

When I run my code, I don't get any errors, but the code isn't going anything. I originally thought that this was a problem with file permissions, but I'm still having the problem after changing them. Not sure what to try next.

Here's the code:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

# create a function to delete unnecessary variables from a CAFAS or PECFAS 
data set and save the reduced copy

del.items <- function(file)
{  
  data <- read.csv(input = paste0("../data/pecfas|cafas/raw", 
str_match(pattern = "cafas|pecfas", string = file) %>% tolower, "/raw/", 
file), sep = ",", header = TRUE, na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
skip = 0, colClasses = "character", data.table = FALSE)

  data <- data[-grep(pattern = "^(CA|PEC)FAS_E[0-9]+(T(Initial|[0-
9]+|Exit)|SP[a-z])_(G|S|Item)[0-9]+$", x = names(data))]

  write.csv(data, file = paste0("../data/pecfas|cafas/items-del", 
str_match(pattern = "cafas|pecfas", string = file) %>% tolower, "/items-
del/", sub(pattern = "ExportData_", x = file, replacement = "")) %>% 
tolower, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
}

# delete items from all cafas data sets

cafas.files <- list.files("../data/cafas/raw/", pattern = ".csv")

for (file in cafas.files){
  del.items(file)
}

# delete items from all pecfas data sets

pecfas.files <- list.files("../data/pecfas/raw/", pattern = ".csv")

 for (file in pecfas.files){
  del.items(file)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the code isn't going anything" ? Are no files created?  Are the files created but empty?  Are the files not empty but not cleaned?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. No files are being created at all, and I don't know if they're even reading the files in the first place.

Comment: I would recommend that you step through the code and try to figure out where it is failing.    First,  run the statement, `cafas.files <- list.files("../data/cafas/raw/", pattern = ".csv")` and print out `cafas.files`.  Is it finding any files to process?  If it is, take the first one and step it through the code.

Comment: Write  `file = cafas.files[1]` and then step through the lines of `del.items`   i.e. try `data <- read.csv(input = paste0("../data/pecfas|cafas/raw", 
str_match(pattern = "cafas|pecfas", string = file) %>% tolower, "/raw/", 
file), sep = ",", header = TRUE, na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
skip = 0, colClasses = "character", data.table = FALSE)`   Did that work?  anything in `data`  keep going to see where it fails.

Comment: Tip: get rid of those `input = paste0(...) %>% tolower` and `file = paste0(...) %>% tolower`, do that before the `read.csv` and `write.csv`, and use `print` statements to see what those beings are.

Comment: G5W: It's not finding any files to process.

Comment: Rui Barradas: Can you clarify what you mean? Do you mean to physically delete that part of the code?

Comment: @G5W After changing some things, it's creating new .csv files in the right place, with the right file names, but the files that it is creating are empty. I'm getting warning messages saying that the attempt to set col.names and sep were ignored.